# ViewFlipper stacks child views on 'outAnimation'

Tags: android, android-layout, viewflipper, android-animation, android-xml

I have a viewFlipper which flips between many textViews.
For some reason the views stack on outAnimation. instead of just one performing 'in animation' and one performing 'out animation' I got one performing 'in animation' and all previous views performing 'out animation', Can somebody help me achieve a state where views dont stack upon each other on out animation?

Here is the flipper xml:

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"      
        android:background="#60000000"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/flipper_transition_in"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/flipper_transition_out"
        android:autoStart="true"
        android:flipInterval="5000">

        <TextView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="אין דבר העומד בפני הרצון"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#00ff00"
            android:singleLine="true"
            >
            </TextView> 

        <TextView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="קשה – זאת אומרת אפשר"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#00ff00"
            android:singleLine="true"
            >
            </TextView>
        <TextView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="מי שלא מעז – לא מצליח"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#00ff00"
            android:singleLine="true"
            >
            </TextView>
        <TextView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="אל תצפה לזה - תעבוד בשביל זה"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#00ff00"
            android:singleLine="true"
            >
            </TextView>
        <TextView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="אל תוותר על מה שאתה רוצה"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#00ff00"
            android:singleLine="true"
            >
            </TextView>
        <TextView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="דברים גדולים דורשים זמן"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#00ff00"
            android:singleLine="true"
            >
            </TextView>     
        <TextView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="כשתגיע לשם תצחק על כולם"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#00ff00"
            android:singleLine="true"
            >
            </TextView>
```

And here are the animation xmls:

in animation:

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
>
 <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="5000"/>
```

out animation:

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    >
 <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="5000"/>
```

notice my animation translates the text from left to right, this is what i need, not a mistake.
any help would be greatly appreciated!!! thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to have a close tag if using the set animation. But since you are only doing one animation there is no need for the set tag.

Comment: there is a </set> tag if thats what you mean... otherwise eclipse wouldnt let me compile it. anyway, do you have a clue why i got my views stacked up in the outAnimation? i tried clearDisappearingChildren() but it didnt help... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey your code seems to work. I did make a small change in the viewflipper tag.

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1" android:background="#60000000"
    android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left" 
    android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right"
    android:autoStart="true" android:flipInterval="5000">
```

Instead of using the animation code you wrote, I used the animation in the android sdk.
Btw your code doesn't have an end viewflipper tag. And instead of using 
use . You are not enclosing anything so the end tag isn't really necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that will suffice for now, although I cant' tell if the views stack up with this animation (not that its necessary because of the speed). If you ever come across a way to make a translating, constant speed animation that does not stack up views, please post it here :)

Comment: By the way, where in the sdk can i see all provided animations?

Comment: in eclipse, if you you hit android.R. you will get a list of all the resources in the sdk. Btw set the answer,upvote please. Then Im not sure what your requirement, as the above method is how you cycle between views. But if your looking for a continous slider this might help https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo

Comment: Thanks this is exactly the effect i needed. Sorry, can't upvote, says i need reputation of at least 15 for that:P